# VNET with class cloud service

Tags: azure

I am using a VNET to connect a VM with a classic cloud service. This works fine as long as I use the classic VNET. When I try to use the "new" VNET and deploy my package, I retrieve an Error

> the virtual network does not exist

Is there any way to work with the "new" VNET and classic cloud services?

Answer (score 1):

Is this VM created as a classic VM (Service Management Model)? As far as I know, you cannot join resources that are created in the different management models.

http://www.capaxglobal.com/blog/using-azure-classic-and-azure-resource-manager-together

Differences explained:
https://azure.microsoft.com/nl-nl/documentation/articles/resource-manager-deployment-model/